# Is there a difference between Foo<dynamic>(...) and Foo<object>(...)?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm reviewing some code and I've found the following:

```
public static void Foo<T>(T t) { //whatever }

dynamic someDynamicValue = ....
Foo(someDynamicValue); //does making this call dynamicly make any sense?
```

If you actually check the type of `T` inside `Foo` you will see it is `object`. So, why not simply force the type of the argument to `object` and skip the whole runtime price of letting type inference resolve to `dynamic`?

```
var someDynamicValue = ....
Foo(someDynamic as object);
```

Important note: I *know* with complete certainty that `someDynamic` is not a value type.

Am I missing something and sublty changing the semantics of the code or is this an innocuous modification?

Another matter altoghether would be if the signature of `Foo` where `Foo<dynamic>(dynamic t)`, in which case the generic type argument would resolve to the runtime type and not `object`. But that is not the case.

Comment: *If you actually check the type of T inside Foo you will see it is object* then what the point in having this generic method at all?

Comment: @TimSchmelter `someDynamicValue` is `dynamic`, I'll make it clearer (the variable is assigned form a method returning a `dynamic`.

Comment: @Rahul Because that method is also being called with non dynamic arguments. The method is not the point, its making the call dynamicly what seems pointless and thats why I am asking if simply casting to `object` would change anything.

Comment: I do not believe that `dynamic` counts as an actual type. Even if `someDynamicValue` is a dynamic, there is still some underlying type. Since the compiler cannot determine that at compile time (since it’s dynamic and not a statically available type), it will use the most generic type which is `object`.

Comment: You are not changing the semantics of *existing* code. But if, in the future, someone adds an overload for `Foo(MyParticularType)`, your cast to `object` means this overload will not be invoked.

Comment: @poke exactly, the generic type resolves to `object` but the argument is *still* `dynamic` therefore the call will be resolved at runtime (?), something that doesn't happen if you previously cast it to `object`. You are paying a runtime price that seems completely unnecessary.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Hmm, I'm not following you. I'm only casting `dynamic` variables to `object` *at the callsite*. If someone performs a call `Foo(myParticularType)` with no `dynamic` arguments, `T` will be correclty inferred.

Comment: If `someDynamicValue` actually contains an object of type `MyParticularType` that happens to be stored as `dynamic`, and there is a non-generic overload `Foo(MyParticularType)`, then leaving it as `dynamic` will call that overload. Your cast to `object` forces `Foo<object>` to be invoked instead. If you control `Foo` and all of its overloads, you might not consider that a problem, but it is a semantic change. Think future-proofing here.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ah! Very good point, didn't understand you at first.

Comment: As noted in the marked duplicate, and in the comments above, there's a _big_ difference between casting the parameter to `object` and leaving it as `dynamic`. `dynamic` is not a type per se; instead, it's a signal to the C# compiler that compilation of the section of code using the `dynamic` type should be deferred to run-time. ...

Comment: ... This includes deferring overload resolution. If you cast to `object`, the overload is selected at compile-time, based on the type `object` only. If you don't, the overload resolution happens at run-time, based on the run-time type of the parameter, which could select a different overload (should a more appropriate one exist at that time).